# Request within Lambda to ApiGateway resulting in The Request could not be satisfied

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, lambda, gateway

As the title suggests I am not longer able to make a request to a apiGateway of mine from a lambda as a the result returns the following response.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd\">\n<HTML><HEAD><META HTTP-EQUIV=\"Content-Type\" CONTENT=\"text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\">\n<TITLE>ERROR: The request could not be satisfied</TITLE>\n</HEAD><BODY>\n<H1>403 ERROR</H1>\n<H2>The request could not be satisfied.</H2>\n<HR noshade size=\"1px\">\nBad request.\nWe can't connect to the server for this app or website at this time. There might be too much traffic or a configuration error. Try again later, or contact the app or website owner.\n<BR clear=\"all\">\nIf you provide content to customers through CloudFront, you can find steps to troubleshoot and help prevent this error by reviewing the CloudFront documentation.\n<BR clear=\"all\">\n<HR noshade size=\"1px\">\n<PRE>\nGenerated by cloudfront (CloudFront)\nRequest ID: k1qZjmDT_kv8462L0aF3susozg_A1OwFoM1piBKU2CT_m5tV9_aArQ==\n</PRE>\n<ADDRESS>\n</ADDRESS>\n</BODY></HTML>
```

This was previously working but at some point it has stopped working. If I try another apiGateway, with a different method, it works. I'm writing this thread on here as I don't have an AWS account that allows for technical support queries.

All infrastructure is built using the Serverless Application Model. Additionally, the lambda communicates to the Api Gateway directly instead of any named domain. No application has Cloudfront or anything attached to it so this message is very bizzare. If I use postman the request works so it makes me feel something has messed up DNS wise but I would be a little bit naive to think Amazon could mess something like that up.

Answer (score 7):

I was passing body data with a GET request so AWS Api Gateway was actively rejecting the request. The message given was just not helpful enough.

Comment: This was super helpful, dunno why it doesn't have more views/votes